# Cucumber Java and Cucumber JS

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumberjs

My team has developed a Cucumber JS app to run BDD functional tests for all our applications. I am now trying to switch it over to Cucumber Java. My question is, can I setup the app to work with both .ts and .java step definition files.

We are trying to avoid setting up two different apps right now and I am looking for ways to keep the existing app and eventually switch over all apps within it to Cucumber Java. I assume since cucumber-java can not be installed thru npm, this will not be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello! MAYBE, you may try to research into the Java Nashorn. Nashorn is a JavaScript engine that is used to execute JavaScript at JVM (Java Virtual Machine).
But I am really not sure it is suitable for you.

Comment: INFO: If your team are using JS, why are you trying to switch to Java?